# API endpoint to get most-read and popular posts

Tags: posts, popular-posts

I am reading [Endpoint reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) exposed from wordpress api but I don't see an endpoint to get most read post(s) and popular post.

There is an endpoint to retreive all posts [https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/post](https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts).

Is there an endpoint or query parameter(s) missing to get most read post(s) and popular post without use a wordpress plugin (wordpress beginner) ?

Answer (score -1):

```
 Check the below article it will help you to get the popular posts
 with the WordPress REST API and please let me know your thoughts:
```

https://medium.com/fiatinsight/find-popular-posts-with-the-wordpress-rest-api-109013bdc5e3